# Replace @TypeDef with Hibernate 6 equivalent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to upgrade hibernate from 5.7.x to version 6. In version 6 the @TypeDef and more other annotations are deprecated and I want to convert my code to be compatible to this new version.
I uses jasypt to encrypt a field of the Entity.
This is my current code:

```
@TypeDef(name = "encryptedUserMail", typeClass = org.jasypt.hibernate5.type.EncryptedStringType.class, parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "encryptorRegisteredName", value = "encryptorUserName") })
```

```
@Column(name = "email")
    @Email
    @Type(type = "encryptedUserMail")
    @Override
    public String getEmail() {
        return super.getEmail();
    }
```

How do I convert this to work in hibernate 6?

I read the documentation on the release, but couldn't find nothing specific. Also is jasypt there is no package for hibernate6.

Can anyone suggest a solution this straight-forward as it is?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Got the same issue

Comment: @KaijuDeluxe check the answer if it is still an issue, or suggest an alternative if you found one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried multiple solutions I found this one to work. Basicly you make a concrete converter, I will leave the code here.

```
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.Converter;
import org.jasypt.hibernate5.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Converter
public class Encrypt implements AttributeConverter<String,String> {
    @Autowired
    HibernatePBEStringEncryptor encryptor;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String s) {
        return encryptor.encrypt(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
       return encryptor.decrypt(s);
   }
}
```

And a factory for it:

```
import org.jasypt.hibernate5.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EncryptFactory {

@Bean
HibernatePBEStringEncryptor ecriptorFactory(){
    HibernatePBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new HibernatePBEStringEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPassword("changeit");
    return encryptor;
}
```

}

And you use it like this:

```
@Column(name = "email")
@Email
@Convert(converter = Encrypt.class)
@Override
public String getEmail() {
    return super.getEmail();
}
```

Comment: Pretty good! Thanks a lot! Important for other guys, don’t save the password in code therefore I will use jasypt